# Show that for $p$ prime, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the only finite field with cardinality $p$ (not counting Isomorphism)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> Show that for $p$ prime, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the only finite field with cardinality $p$ (not counting Isomorphism)

So here my proof. I know that the elements are $p$, in particular  $\mathbb{Z}_p=\{ 0,1,2,...,p-1\}$. If I suppose there is another field $\mathbb{K}_p=\{ 0,1,2,...,p-1\}$ with $p$ elements, I want to show that $\mathbb{Z}_p==\mathbb{K}_p$.

An element mod $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p $ exist also in $\mathbb{K}_p$ so $\mathbb{Z}_p \subset \mathbb{K}_p$. But it's valid also the vice versa $\mathbb{Z}_p \supset \mathbb{K}_p$. Plus, every operation made using elements $z_i$ can fall into the $\mathbb{K}_p$ set and every operation made using elements $k_i$ can fall into the $\mathbb{Z}_p$ set.
If those fields are finite, then must be $char(\mathbb{Z}_p) = p$ and $char(\mathbb{K}_p) = p$, so must be $\mathbb{Z}_p==\mathbb{K}_p$.

Are those evidence sufficient to prove the assertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your proof but I don't think that it's correct - you haven't really justified that every element of $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ lies in $\mathbb{K}_p$, and then I'm not sure what your next sentence means. I think you have the right idea but haven't quite worded your proof correctly!

Here are the steps you should follow : suppose $K$ is a field with $p$ elements and multiplicative identity $1_K$. Let $\phi\,:\,\mathbb{Z}/(p) \rightarrow K$ be the ring homomorphism sending $1 \mapsto 1_K$, and show that this must be an isomorpsism

Comment: $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow K$ is an homomorphism because $\phi(1+z_i) = \phi(1)+\phi(z_i) = 1_k+k_i$. For the product $\phi(1 \times z_i) = \phi(1) \times \phi(z_i) = 1_k \times k_i = k_i$ so the mapping should be complete, and the proof too. Do I miss something yet? I have great difficulties to use the formalism, sorry

Comment: Think about the kernel of $\phi$ and what we can say about it, knowing that $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ has prime order.

Comment: We know that if $\mathbb{Z_p}$ has order $p$ with $p$ prime, then $Ker \phi \not = 0$; this reminds me of the algebraic condition or the minimal polynomial. For the algebraic condition, it also mean that is a finite field...?